# Figuring out performance issues

Tags: react-native

For the last few days I've been fighting performance issues of FlatList inside application I've created.

FlatList consists of static header and x rows. In the measured case there are 62 rows, every one of them consists of 4 components - one of them is used 4 times, which sums up to 7 row cells. Every cell of this list is either TouchableNativeFeedback or TouchableOpacity (for testing purpose those have attached `() => null` to onPress. There is shouldComponentUpdate used on few levels (list container, row, single cell) and I think render performance is good enough for that kind of list.

For consistent measurements I've used `initialNumToRender={data.length}`, so whole list renders at once. List is rendered using button, data loading isn't part of my measurement - it's preloaded to component local state.

According to attached Chrome Performance Profile JS thread takes 1.33s to render component. I've used CPU slowdown x6 to simulate Android device more accurately.

However, list shows up on device at around 15s marker, so actual render from button press to list showing up takes more than 14s!

What I am trying to figure out is what happens between JS rendering component and component actually showing up on screen, because device is 
unresponsive whole that time. Every touch event is registered, but it is played out only when the list is finally on screen.

I've attached trace from chrome dev tools, systrace taken using android systrace tool and screen from android profiler (sadly I couldn't find option to export the latter).

Tracing was run almost simultaneously - the order is systrace, android profiler, chrome dev tools.

What are the steps that I should make to help me understand what's going on while the app freezes?

[Simple reproduction application (code in src.js, first commit)](https://github.com/XenorPLxx/perfapp/tree/99f514ae72174125de261df1ab154134d710c56b)

[Chrome Performance Profile](http://www19.zippyshare.com/v/ZDKBPLHm/file.html)
[image: Chrome Performance Profile]

[Systrace HTML](http://www19.zippyshare.com/v/22oLQH7B/file.html)
[image: Systrace HTML]

Android Profiler
[image: Android Profiler]

Comment: Are you able to create a reproduction on e.g. snack.expo.io ?

Comment: I have reproduction app ready, but it's waiting for release approval. I've be back at it first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: I've added link to reproduction app repo in the first post

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source code you posted](https://github.com/XenorPLxx/perfapp/blob/ae10c2e9b006afb671000cf5104be0cf8d19416b/src.js), I don't think this is a React rendering problem.

The issue is that you're doing too much work in your `render` method and the helper methods you are calling during the render pass.

Every time you call `.filter`, `.forEach` or `.map` on an array, the entire list is iterated over `n` times. When you do this for `m` components, you get a computational complexity of `O(n * m)`.

For example, this is the `TransportPaymentsListItem` render method:

```
/**
 * Render table row
 */
render() {
  const {
    chargeMember,
    obligatoryChargeNames,
    sendPayment,
    eventMainNavigation
  } = this.props;

  /**
   *  Filters obligatory and obligatory_paid_in_system charges for ChargeMember
   */
  const obligatoryChargesWithSys = this.props.chargeMember.membership_charges.filter(
    membershipCharge =>
      membershipCharge.type === "obligatory" ||
      membershipCharge.type === "obligatory_paid_in_system"
  );

  /**
   *  Filters obligatory charges for ChargeMember
   */
  const obligatoryCharges = obligatoryChargesWithSys.filter(
    membershipCharge => membershipCharge.type === "obligatory"
  );

  /**
   *  Filters obligatory adjustments for ChargeMember
   */
  const obligatoryAdjustments = this.props.chargeMember.membership_charges.filter(
    membershipCharge =>
      membershipCharge.type === "optional" &&
      membershipCharge.obligatory === true
  );

  /**
   *  Filters obligatory trainings for ChargeMember
   */
  const obligatoryTrainings = this.props.chargeMember.membership_charges.filter(
    membershipCharge =>
      membershipCharge.type === "training" &&
      membershipCharge.obligatory === true
  );

  /**
   *  Filters paid obligatory adjustments for ChargeMember
   */
  const payedObligatoryTrainings = obligatoryTrainings.filter(
    obligatoryTraining =>
      obligatoryTraining.price.amount ===
      obligatoryTraining.amount_paid.amount
  );

  // This one does a .forEach as well...
  const sums = this.calculatedSums(obligatoryCharges);

  // Actually render...
  return (
```

In the sample code there are 11 such iterator calls. For the dataset of 62 rows you have used, the array iterators are called total of **4216** times! Even if every iterator is very simple comparison, simply iterating through all those lists is too slow and blocks the main JS thread.

To solve this, you should lift the state transformation higher up in the component chain, so that you can only do the iteration once and build up a view model that you can pass down the component tree and render declaratively without additional work.

Comment: Thanks!
You're definitely making a good point and the way I provide data to components should be revised.
Still, my understanding is `render` method runs in JS thread (`mqt_js`), not in `mqt_native_modules`. Documentation says that `TouchableNativeFeedback` is Native Module wrapped. It doesn't say anything about `FlatList`. I've swapped all `TouchableNativeFeedback` for `TouchableOpacity`, so all work should be done in JS Thread, but still got only ~1,5s of work in Chrome Profiler.

So is my understanding of problem wrong and actually everything in `render` runs in `mqt_native_modules`?

Comment: All primitive views, including `TouchableOpacity`, `View`, `Text` are native modules wrapped in JavaScript. `FlatList` isn't, but it uses native views internally. I'm not sure about the profiler stats, but it does sound like `mqt_js` should encompass the main JS thread. However, as a point of comparison, I have some UI components that render a lot more Views than your list, and the render perf on mount is not affected. Similarly, changing the Touchable* components to Views doesn't significantly improve the rendering speed in your code. I don't unfortunately have time to dig into the profiling.

Comment: Okay, I guess the simplest test I can perform would be removing all that `.map`, `.filter` and `.forEach` calls and trying to render my components with totally static data to see how almost pure drawing will perform. I was convinced that all those filtering calls are run in the first ~1.5 seconds, when `mqt_js` is showing activity and it didn't seem like much comparing to ~13,5s of `mqt_native_modules` activity time. I'll get back with results when I'll have the time to do some testing.

Comment: You may very well be right. I just don't see anything in the code that would warrant that high mounting cost, but I'm very open to being wrong.

Comment: Okay, I've done static data test and still got same results. I think problem is with how I am profiling. I've been running every test in remote debugging, so I can see functions waterfall in Chrome. It makes `mqt_js` run in browser instead on device and even with CPU 6x slowdown it still seems to be too fast. `mqt_native_modules` on the other hand still runs on the device, which makes it go slow. Profiling in Android Studio with debugging turned off shows that actually `mqt_js` does much more work than `mqt_native_modules`, which makes your suggestion to optimise state transformation on point.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying different things for a while now, I was even considering wrapping native Android RecyclerView, but to be fair, it seemed quite a challenge as I've had no prior experience with native Android code.

One of the things I've tried over the past few days was using [react-native-largelist](https://github.com/bolan9999/react-native-largelist), but it didn't deliver promised performance improvement. To be fair, it might've been even slower than `FlatList`, but I didn't take exact measurements.

After few days of googling, coding and profiling I've finally managed to get my hands on [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@naqvitalha/recyclerlistview-high-performance-listview-for-react-native-and-web-e368d6f0d7ef), which references [recyclerlistview](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview) package and it seems to provide better experience than FlatList. For profiled case rendering time dropped to about 2s, including 300ms of JS thread work.

It's mandatory to notice that improvement of initial rendering comes from reduced number of items rendered (11 in my case). `FlatList` with `initialNumToRender={11}` setting renders initially in about the same time.

In my case initial rendering, while still important, isn't the only thing that matters. `FlatList` performance drops for larger lists mainly because while scrolling it keeps all rendered rows in memory, while `recyclerlistview` recycles rendered rows putting in new data.

Reason of observer performance improvement for re-rendering is actually simple to test. I've added `console.log` to `shouldComponentUpdate` in my row component and counted how many rows is actually re-rendered. For my row height and test device resolution `recyclerlistview` re-renders only 17 rows, while `FlatList` triggers `shouldComponentUpdate` for every item in dataset. It's also worth noticing that number of rows re-rendered for `recyclerlistview` is not dependent on dataset size.

My conclusion is that `FlatList` performance may degrade even more with bigger datasets, while `recyclerlistview` speed should stay at similar level.

`TouchableNativeFeedback` inside `recyclerlistview` also seem to be more responsive, as the animation fires up without delay, but I can't explain that behaviour looking at profilers.

There's definitely still room for improvement in my row component, but for now I am happy with overall list rendering performance.

[Simple reproduction application with recyclerlistview (code in src.js, second commit)](https://github.com/XenorPLxx/perfapp/tree/ae10c2e9b006afb671000cf5104be0cf8d19416b)

Chrome Performance Profile (recyclerlistview)
[image: Chrome Performance Profile (recyclerlistview)]

Systrace HTML (recyclerlistview)
[image: Systrace HTML (recyclerlistview)]

Answer (score 1):

Just give one more source to try.

You can enable Hermes in android/app/build.gradle like this.

```
project.ext.react = [
        entryFile   : "index.js",
        enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
```

My app not crashing but the touchable will stop working after some heavy process. When this happens, the process is still running ok, the app's drawer is still working. But all touchable in my app stop working without any error message. I spent 3 days to find a solution and finally tried hermes. On [react native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/hermes), it says

`Hermes is an open-source JavaScript engine optimized for running React Native apps on Android.`

Comment: Oh I've heard about Hermes and it looks great, I'm not working on that project anymore tho :D.